# Задача о сложении цифр двухзначного числа

Tags: c++

В цикле у пользователь спрашивается ввести число , если 0 тогда выход , число например 23 , 75 ,78  в конце выводит сумму 2 чисел , например 23 = 2+3 = 5 , 75 = 7+5 = 12 , 78 = 7+8=15 .

Вывод примерно такой

Макс число 15 из числа 78.

по условию нельзя использовать массивы и другие коллекции.

Comment: Я не понял, причем здесь "Макс число 15 из числа 78"?!

Comment: например есть числа 23 75 78 
сумма цифр каждого числа отдельно 
сумма 23 будет 2+3 = 5
сумма 75 будет 7+5 = 12 
сумма 78 будет 7+8 = 15 

максимум из них всех число 15 которое мы получили из 78

Comment: @user2420249 это явно домашнее задание. вы пытались решить его самостоятельно?

Comment: всю суть как решить я знаю ровно до момента где их хранить ? если массивы запрещены  , и как их потом сравнивать

Comment: Вас сейчас заминусят, конечно. Считывайте по 1 числу, для вновь введенного считайте сумму его цифр. Если она больше текущей максимальной - то обновите последнюю. (То есть вначале заводите max = 0) а в цикле  `if (sumOfDigit(сумма цифр) > max)max = sumOfDigit` max и будет ответом. (ну если надо, там же и само число запоминайте)

Comment: @user2420249  Так надо найти максимум из сумм цифр?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лови.:)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a sequence of non-negative numbers (0 - stop): ";

    unsigned int value;
    unsigned int max_value = 0;
    unsigned int max_sum = 0;

    while ( std::cin >> value && value != 0 )
    {
        const unsigned int Base = 10;

        unsigned int sum = 0;
        unsigned int x = value;

        do { sum += x % Base; } while ( x /= Base );

        if ( max_sum < sum )
        {
            max_sum   = sum;
            max_value = value;
        }
    }

    if ( max_sum != 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "The maximum sum of digits is " << max_sum
                  << " for number " << max_value
                  << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "You have not enetered numbers" << std::endl;
    }        
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть как

```
Enter a sequence of non-negative numbers (0 - stop): 23 75 78 0
The maximum sum of digits is 15 for number 78
```

Comment: Спасибо ! решение действительно простое , в след раз буду внимательней .

Comment: @user2420249 Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, пусть домашние/учебные/и т.п. задачи сами решают.